# Can we automate a sequence of API calls for functional testing using karate framework?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cucumber, web-api-testing, karate

I am currently performing unit testing of rest APIs using karate-framework. Can we automate functional test cases through a sequence of different API calls using karate framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a **big** YES. Kindly refer to the [demo examples](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo), for example - this one: [`cats.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/cats/cats.feature).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I figured it out myselftafter asking the question.. But I need one help. How to read input values from excel data sheet using karate framework?